# How to call Webservice through jquery?

Tags: jquery, web-services

How to call webservice through jquery... I tried following code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
         $("#sayHelloButton").click(function(event){   
             $.ajax({   
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "C:/Webservice/Service.asmx/HelloToYou",   
                 data: "{'name': '" + $('#name').val() + "'}",   
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
                 dataType: "json",   
                 success: function(msg) {   
                     AjaxSucceeded(msg);   
                 },   
                 error: AjaxFailed   
             });   
         });   
     });   
          function AjaxSucceeded(result) {   
              alert(result.d);   
          }   
          function AjaxFailed(result) {   
              alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);   
          }
```

My doubt is where my web service should be? Whether I need to publish it and use that path or the service should be within the same solution..

Plz, Clear my doubt

Comment: The webservice should be in the same domain as where the javascript file came from, so the url is just url: "Service.asmx/HelloToYou"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the URL is on the same server as the HTML page.  There are various ways to specify the URL without explicitly writing out the hostname, such as:

```
url: "/Webservice/Service.asmx/HelloToYou",
```

C:/ is definitely incorrect, though.

Comment: Actually, My webservice is hosted in the main server in separate path. Now, I need to manage with that. No way to use my web service through jquery now????